# object jump is not correct C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am trying to make a tilemap platformer with unity. For the charecter i am using a box collider 2d and a rigidbody. for the ground I am using a tilemap collider with a composite collider. here is my script

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharecterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float jumpHeight;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
            rb.velocity += new Vector2(1, 0) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
            rb.velocity += new Vector2(-1, 0) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
            rb.velocity += new Vector2(0, jumpHeight) * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with my script is sometimes it jumps really high, and sometimes really low

low jump:
[image]

high jump:
[image]

how do i fix this?

EDIT:- is this something to do with the rigidBody? should i replace it with a charectercontroller? and how do i use the charecter controller?

Comment: 1, Modify velocity in FixedUpdate. 2, Don't modify velocity. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the speed of `Update()` so things like `Input.GetKey` are frame rate dependant and may be called hundreds of times a second. It would be best to put a timer on the input e.g.:

```
float t = 0;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && t < 1){
            rb.velocity += new Vector2(1, 0) * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        t += Time.deltaTime;
        if (t > 1) t = 0;
    }
```